# Create schedule for iOS grayscale display

Tags: ios, night-shift

I wish to make my iPhone’s screen grayscale following a schedule. I am able to turn on grayscale mode manually, and I am able to schedule “Night Shift”, which changes the color profile of the screen, but I am unable to schedule a color profile shift entirely to grayscale.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to "Color Filter" in settings and choose greyscale. Then set an automation to enable Color Filter.